# QML udp/rtp video stream fails Windows 10

Tags: windows, qml, rtp, qt6, qtmultimedia

In Qt5 /qml it was possible to playback udp stream as **rtp** payload on Windows MSVC kit , below qml code works on Qt5, now problem is migrating to qt6 (6.3) this stopped working anymore, No error reported .. only if I check Video element error, I get `Failed to load source` ;  in **Qt6**, QMultimedia *back end* is Windows **media foundation** ,  as of [Qt supported-media-formats](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/videooverview.html#supported-media-formats) Under Widows section , It seems that whatever Windows media player can decode and play ..so should also Qt do, strangely, I can play the stream with same url using Windows media player , which also uses media foundation. I also have installed the K-Lite codec pack from codec guide in same reference .. , notably, Qt can detect erroneous url and reports `Unsupported url scheme!` if the url was erratic , this is not the case! Is this a bug in Qt6 .. or ?

code

GStreamer streaming pipeline ..
`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./local_video.mp4 ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! queue ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.174 port=5005`

QML code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtMultimedia


Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Component.onCompleted: {
        mediaplayer.source = "rtp://192.168.0.174:5005/? udpsrc.caps=application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26"
        //mediaplayer.source = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        mediaplayer.play()
    }
    Video {
        id: mediaplayer
        width: 640
        height: 480
        onErrorChanged: console.log("play error", mediaplayer.errorString , error) // Failed to load source
    }
}
```

Comment: should'n it be "rtSp"//***"? also `mediaplayer.source` is a url type, the line that you pass doesn't looks like url. anyway, I would check the same QML code with some external url from the Internet to be sure it works with the same backend.

Comment: @folibis why you think `.source` is not a url , it is a fully qualified url , `rstp` is not needed here , GStreamer pipeline is an `rtp` payload

Comment: does the same Url works with VLC?

Comment: @folibis  VLC is different , it needs an SDP file , I only have this code already working with Qt5